# call jquery function with html onclick attribute

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django

How to call a jquery function using html button's onclick attribute?
I have a html form which is being generated using a for loop. Like:

```
{% for sku, name, mrp, sp, id in product_data_list %}
    <form id="add_to_cart" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <li class="item col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="item-inner">
            ....
            ....
         <button class="button btn-cart" type="submit" id="product_id" value="{{id}}"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
          ....
```

My jquery function sends an ajax request to django view. The problem is my jquery function only catches the first element generated by form and sends the ajax request successfully but it is not processing any other element generated by the for loop.
So I want to bind jquery function to each form element being generated by the for loop.

But i don't know how to do that.

Jquery code:

```
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('#add_to_cart').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : "/add_to_cart/", // the endpoint
            type : "POST",
            cache: false,
            async: "true",
            data : { product_id : $('#product_id').val()}, // data sent with the post request

        success : function(json) {
            console.log("success");
            alert("Product Added To Cart.")
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log(errmsg);
        }
    });
  });});
</script>
```

Comment: I guess you are adding form inside loop. So id will be coming multiple times. In this case same id exists multiple times, which should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
<form id="add_to_cart" action="{% url 'add_to_cart' %}" method="POST">    
{% for sku, name, mrp, sp, id in product_data_list %}

    {% csrf_token %}
        <li class="item col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <div class="item-inner">
            ....
            ....
         <button class="button btn-cart" type="submit" id="product_id" value="{{id}}"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>
```

I guess this will work.

Comment: No this will not as the ajax request will check for the first element and it will always POST the first element's data. I have already tried that.

Comment: i think that product_id is repeating inside the loop.  " <button class="button btn-cart" type="submit" id="product_id" value="{{id}}"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>"

Comment: please try to make the product id as unique. Something like this " <button class="button btn-cart" type="submit" id="product_id_{{id}}" value="{{id}}"><span>Add to Cart</span></button>". and send all the product id values as data

Comment: ok i did that `id="product_id_{{id}}"`. Now how to access the variable in my jquery function?

Comment: var button_values = $(".button_class").map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
}).get(); This will return an array of values.  'button_class' should be the unique class for the buttons